# compare two list and Increment QTY if item exists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom

I am moving selected item from a list to another.

i want to increase the quantity of a field it the item already exists.
Please see my existing code is below.

I add or update the list based on the comparison clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

is not getting called?

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var olist111;
    function AddToCart() {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web);

        var sourceId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        var source = web.get_lists().getById(sourceId);

        var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
        context.load(oList);

        var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
        var spItems = [];

        //alert('debut');
        for (i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
            var currentItem = source.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
            //alert(selectedItems[i].id);
            context.load(currentItem);
            spItems.push(currentItem);

        }
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {

            for (var j = 0; j < spItems.length; j++) {
                // pass use ID + product name
                var compareFun = Compare(spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name') + "#" + spItems[j].get_item('ID'));
                olist111 = spItems;
                compareFun.done(function (data) {
                    var Match = data;

                    if (typeof Match === 'string' || Match instanceof String) {
                        alert("Item already exists in the chart");
                        alert(Match);
                        var tmpstr = Match.split("#");
                        alert(tmpstr[0]);
                        alert(tmpstr[1]);
                        var Productname = tmpstr[0];

                        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
                        alert('Updated');
                        var oList1 = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
                        alert("Updated 2");
                        var oListItem = oList1.getItemById(tmpstr[1]);
                        alert("Updated 3");
                        oListItem.set_item('QTY', 2);
                        oListItem.update();
                        alert('Updated');
                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

                    }

                    else if (Match == 0) {
                        alert("Item not in the chart");
                    }
                }).fail(function (sender, args) { alert('Failed'); });
                console.log("index" + spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
            }
            function onQuerySucceeded() {

                alert('Item updated!');
            }

            function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
            //context.executeQueryAsync(success);
            //   alert('done');

        }), Function.createDelegate(this, error));


        function success(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function error(sender, args) { alert('error'); }
    }

    function updateListItem(str) {
        alert(1);
        alert(str);
        var tmpstr = str.split("#");
        alert(tmpstr[0]);
        alert(tmpstr[1]);
        var Productname = tmpstr[0];

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
        this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(tmpstr[1]);
        oListItem.set_item('QTY', 2);
        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {

        alert('Item updated!');
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }



    function Compare(str) {
        alert(str);
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var tmpstr = str.split("#");
        var Productname = tmpstr[0];
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');

        var skillcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        //skillcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Product_x0020_Name' /><Value Type='Text'>" + str + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
        skillcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query> <Where><And><Eq> <FieldRef Name='Product_x0020_Name'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Productname + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName + "</Value> </Eq> </And> </Where></Query></View>");

        var skillcollListItem = list.getItems(skillcamlQuery);

        clientContext.load(skillcollListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            if (skillcollListItem.get_count() >= 1) {
                dfd.resolve(str);
            }
            else {
                dfd.resolve(0);
            }
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            dfd.reject(sender, args);
        }));
        return dfd.promise();
    }
</script>

 <input name="btnApprove" onclick="AddToCart()" type="button" value="Add To Cart" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set **Title** as unique field.(in your case I think it will be **product name**)
2. write a function to check whether **same item exists or not**.(can be easily achieved by JSOM or REST) [Ref this for code e.g.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/how-to-check-if-a-list-item-exists-or-not-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript)
3. If exist, update **QTY** of same item.
4. If not exist, create new. (which you already have done.)

Comment: so in the above code instead of thosiba i can use the code from your example to compare ?

Comment: i have updated the code as suggested but it still adds the item

Comment: debugg your Compare function and check whats getting in skillcollListItem

Comment: i think executeQueryAsync cannot return a value or when the call is made after the  clientContext.load(skillcollListItem); the control goes back to the main function hence the values are not returned ?

Comment: You can use deferred to hold the values. Ref this https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: i wasn't able to get it to work with deferred as advised. please see the updated code. i am not an expert on this so the code might be wrong if you can advise the changed in the code i would appreciate it.